# Новый атрибут в объекте yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Как в yii2 задать новый атрибут для объекта модели?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В классе модели

```
public $newParam;
```

Прописываете его в `rules`

Comment: а как в behaviors создать его

Comment: Что значит создать в behaviors? В классе?

Comment: Мне нужно в объекте модели создать новый аттрибут

Comment: Новый атрибут создается в классе, выше написал

Comment: Что будет если атрибут конфликтует со связью

Comment: Переименовать атрибут или связь